# Converting a txt File from ANSI to UTF-8 programmatically

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, file, text-files

I need your help here please.
I'm working on a java application that convert data from a txt file into the database , The problem is that the file have ANSI encoding which i can't change because it comes from outside my application ,and when i write the data to the database i got some "???" inside.
My question is , how can i convert the data that i read from the file from ANSI to UTF-8 which can handle those weired symbols.
I've tried the Byte[] to String converting but it didn't work.

Comment: If I get you right you should use UTF-8 when openning the input stream, like `new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @MByD , Thanks a lot for your recommendation, unfortunately i've tried it but it didn't work for me , always the same result.

Comment: Hello Everyone , I've found the answer , and thanks a looot MByD , instead of using UTF-8 as an encoding , i should give the input encoding wich iiis "windows-1252" , and now noo more weiird symbols

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use open a [decoding Reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) like this one:

```
Reader reader = 
   new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName(encodingName));
```

Exaclty which encoding name you should use depends on [which "ANSI" encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964654) the text file was written in. You can find a list of encoding supported by Java 6 [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). If it is an English-language system, it will likely be `windows-1252`.

Writing data to the database correctly depends on configuring the database correctly and (sometimes) providing the right configuration to the JDBC driver.

*You can read more about character encoding handling in [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html) and [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).*

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. what is ANSI?

https://www.cnblogs.com/malecrab/p/5300486.html

#### 2. need libs

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

#### 3. java sample

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.parser.txt.CharsetDetector;
import org.apache.tika.parser.txt.CharsetMatch;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

/**
 *
 * @author wang.qingsong
 * Created on 2021/09/16
 */
@Slf4j
public class FileUtil {

    public static boolean isFileEncodingUtf8(File inputFile) throws IOException {
        return isUtf8(getFileEncoding(inputFile));
    }

    public static String getFileEncoding(File file) throws IOException {
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);) {
            return getInputStreamEncoding(fileInputStream);
        }
    }

    public static String getInputStreamEncoding(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        CharsetDetector charsetDetector = new CharsetDetector();
        BufferedInputStream buffInput = null; // close new BufferedInputStream
        try {
            charsetDetector.setText(
                input instanceof BufferedInputStream ? input : (buffInput = new BufferedInputStream(input)));
            charsetDetector.enableInputFilter(true);
            CharsetMatch cm = charsetDetector.detect();
            return cm.getName();
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(buffInput);
        }
    }

    public static void convertFileToUtf8(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws IOException {
        final String encoding = getFileEncoding(inputFile);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(encoding)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("inputFile encoding can not parsed!");
        }
        if (isUtf8(encoding)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("inputFile is already utf8, no need convert.");
        }

        if (!outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
        }

        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
             InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, encoding);
             // output
             FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
             OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            IOUtils.copy(inputReader, outputWriter);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isUtf8(String encoding) {
        final Set<String> aliases = Sets.newHashSet("utf-8", "utf_8", "utf8");
        for (String utf8 : aliases) {
            if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(utf8, encoding)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```