# how to convert ANSI to utf8 in java?

Tags: java, unicode

I have a text file it is ANSI Encoding, i have to convert it into UTF8 encoding.

My text file is like this
`Stochastic programming is an area of mathematical programming that studies
how to model decision problems under uncertainty. For example, although a
decision might be necessary at a given point in time, essential information
might not be available until a later time.`

Comment: `ANSI encoding is a slightly generic term used to refer to the standard code page on a system`. In other words, it would depend on the locale of the system you're running on. If you mean _ASCII_, the text is already both since standard ASCII characters (<128) map to the same encoding in UTF-8.

Answer (score 10):

You can be explicit with the java.nio.charset.Charset class (windows-1252 is the proper name for ANSI):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get("file.txt");
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(p));
    CharBuffer cb = Charset.forName("windows-1252").decode(bb);
    bb = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(cb);
    Files.write(p, bb.array());
}
```

Or in one line if you prefer =)

```
Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(Charset.forName("windows-1252").decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.txt"))))).array());
```

Answer (score 0):

ASCII character subset maps to the same character encoding in UTF8, so the file does not really need any conversion.

To output a file in UTF-8, you can use:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(filename), "UTF-8");
out.print(text);
out.close();
```

Comment: i try this one but its not convert from ASCII to UTF-8

Comment: I mean, there should be nothing to convert, really.  An ASCII file is already UTF-8 compliant.

Comment: Sorry i mean ANSI to UTF8

Comment: @Lake Sorry, but with accentuated characters the conversion may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\sample.txt"));
    Reader reader =
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but found a link that can help you out here: [Converting a txt File from ANSI to UTF-8 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192910/converting-a-txt-file-from-ansi-to-utf-8-programaticaly)

There were some issues related to this that are explained here: http://www.drillio.com/en/software-development/java/encoded-string-too-long-64kb-limit/

I hope this helps.