# Read ANSI file with polish letters and show in console without Accents

Tags: java, file, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I have this line "ĆćĘęŁŹźł" in file.csv, which is encoded (as Notepad++ shows) as ANSI. How can I correctly show this line in console like CcEeLzzl.

For removing accents I'm using StringUtils.stripAccents(myLine) from apache but still got "��Ee����"

````
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName2));
            while ((sCurrentLine = StringUtils.stripAccents(br.readLine())) != null) {
                System.out.println(StringUtils.stripAccents(sCurrentLine));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }```

I want in COnsole this "CcEeLzzl", not that "ĆćĘęŁŹźł". Please help me.
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe you will find your answere here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141162/how-to-convert-ansi-to-utf8-in-java

Comment: Thank You, @Jonathan !!!) I tried this one. It did convert my file to UTF-8, but I got this line like that Ă†Ă¦EeÂŁďż˝Ĺ¸Âł.

Comment: I suspect the string is correct and no conversion is needed. Look up curiosa's answer, you may have to convert the letters manually.

Comment: The first thing you should try is `br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName2), "windows-1250"));`.  By “console” do you mean a Microsoft Windows command window?

Comment: @VGR, no sorry, by "console" I mean to show line with System.out.println(lineFromANSIFile)

Comment: And where are you viewing the results of your program’s calling System.out.println?

Comment: @VGR Thank You so much!!! changed this line " br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName2));"  to Yours "br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName2), "windows-1250"));" and It perfectly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to apply a custom mapping from polish letters to ascii which is outside the domain of `stripAccents`. Probably you have to define it by yourself, e.g. like done below (only shown for "Ł" and "ł").

Spoiler: no, you don't have to. The ansi on windows encoding was the culprit. With proper decoding `StringUtils.stripAccents` worked fine. See comments. But if you ever leave stripAccents's domain...

```
public void Ll() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Ł", "L");
    map.put("ł", "l");

    System.out.println(Arrays.stream("ŁałaŁała".split("(?!^)"))
            .map(c -> {
                String letter = map.get(c);
                return letter == null ? c : letter;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.joining("")));
}
```

Comment: thank You for answer, but when I put my line from file instead of this string "ŁałaŁała" it doesn't work. It shows "�a�a�a�a". StringUtils also works fine when I try to change "ŁałaŁała" to "LalaLala", but not from ANSI file :(

Comment: Try to read the file this way (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556104/read-and-write-text-in-ansi-format)) `reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(<file name>), "Cp1252"));` Java is utf-8 world, so we have to get it there. That's supposed to read Windows ANSI. And proceed with StringUtils, I suppose :-/ Isn't it a bit late for hardcore coding as of GMT-1?