# Change all txt files decode from ANSI to UTF-8 in folder and subfolders

Tags: java, utf-8

I`ve tried few approaches to complete this task, unfortunately none of them is working.
Main thing is get all txt files path, so i do it with this piece of code:

```
    public static List<String> getFileList() throws IOException {
        int depth = 5;
        String dir = "pathToMainFolder";
        Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get(dir), depth);
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            stream.filter(file -> !Files.isDirectory(file))
                    .map(Path::toString)
                    .filter(file -> file.endsWith("txt"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> paths));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return paths;
    }
```

After that i tried changing decoding of file with this piece of code from
[how to convert ANSI to utf8 in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141162/how-to-convert-ansi-to-utf8-in-java):

```
       for (String path : paths) {
            Path p = Paths.get(path);
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(p));
            CharBuffer cb = Charset.forName("Cp1252").decode(bb);
            bb = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(cb);
            Files.write(p, bb.array());
}
```

It changed files to UTF-8 coding, but file content is far different from my expectations. For example: is should be: `tań` but is is `tañ`, should be `choć` but it is `choæ`.
I tried also creating new files with `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`, i was trying replacing all signs after decode change. Only thing that works is `Normalizer`:

```
            String everything = "";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            try {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = Normalizer.normalize(br.readLine(), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                        .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

                while (line != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = Normalizer.normalize(br.readLine(), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                            .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
                }
                everything = sb.toString();
                System.out.println(everything);
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
```

But it is the last thing i will do after there is no solution. I will also mention that there are 14k+ files to change in folder and subfolders (files are not so long avg 487 lines with few chars in each).
Any approach or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Converting file between two character sets does not need to use Char/Byte Buffer, here is simple call to recode using String and getBytes:

```
private static void recode(Path input, Charset inCharset, Path output, Charset outCharset)
{
    try
    {
        Files.createDirectories(output.getParent());
        Files.write(output, new String(Files.readAllBytes(input), inCharset).getBytes(outCharset));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

You'll need to take care to only run once on your directories, for tests it would be safer to build separate IN/OUT dirs. Your main can be simplified with `Files.find` and process the transformation directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Charset outCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    // Change as required
    Charset inCharset = Charset.forName("Cp1252");
    // OR
    // Charset inCharset  = StandardCharsets.XYZ;
    // OR
    // Charset inCharset = Charset.forName(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

    int depth = 5;
    Path dir = Path.of("pathToMainFolder");
    Path outdir = Path.of("pathToMainFolder.utf8");
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(dir, depth, (p,a) -> a.isRegularFile() && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")))
    {
        stream.forEach(p -> recode(p, inCharset, outdir.resolve(dir.relativize(p)), outCharset));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution, unfortunately got same output as my other solutions: `£zy`, `szczêœcia` and so on.

Comment: You should also check a few sample values of the hex codes for the in/out characters, as your issue may be caused by the display font or encoding used by whatever tool/app you use to view the output files.