# How to generate .txt file as a UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8

I want to write a code to convert UTF-8 encoded in java.I creating "a.txt" file which contains only English characters inside the "a.txt" file.While generating, It's giving me ANSI encoded version but I need UTF-8 encoded version.

*Note:-
**A file does not contain any special characters, it contains only ASCI value.***

I have written below code.

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8")); 
writer.write(content);
```

Comment: This could be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192910/converting-a-txt-file-from-ansi-to-utf-8-programmatically

Comment: You can find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192910/converting-a-txt-file-from-ansi-to-utf-8-programmatically

Comment: If any unique characters are available in the file then it's converting UTF-8 but in our file contains only English characters but not any special symbols(unique characters).@mhasan ,@ Mikita

Comment: Those comments make no sense to me. Also, given your code, there is no such thing as `UTF-18`, there is no such thing as ANSI encoding (it is an imprecise term for character sets whose first 127 characters are ASCII); and if your file only contains ASCII (characters 0 - 127), then it doesn't matter if you use UTF-8 or one of the 'ANSI' encodings. You will need to show a lot more code ([MCVE]), sample input and sample output if you don't want to have this considered as duplicate of the question I linked.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel check my below code BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8")); writer.write(content); writer.close();

Comment: There is no such thing as `UTF-18`, that code should throw an `UnsupportedCharsetException`, and why repeat that code in your comment if it is already in your question?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's typo error, I was willing to write UTF-8 only.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as ANSI encoding (it is an imprecise term for single byte character sets whose first 128 characters are ASCII); and if your file only contains ASCII (characters 0 - 127), then it doesn't matter if you use UTF-8 or one of the 'ANSI' encodings.

Considering that editors infer character sets (or better: guess(!)), and that UTF-8 with only ASCII 0 - 127 is indistinguishable from actual ASCII, or one of the 'ANSI' encodings, this is entirely expected

This means that if you write a file with - for example - only `"ABC"` in UTF-8, it is also valid ASCII, Windows-1252, ISO-8859-x, and any other character set that takes ASCII as its starting point. The editor cannot decide what the actual character set is, and just reports ANSI.

In other words: your code is working ok; it is just the heuristics of your editor that is guessing the wrong character set. In the end, text files are just a stream of bytes that only get meaning when applying the right character set; the character set is not specified in the file itself.

PS: The code in your question has a typo in that it reference `UTF-18`, which does not exist.